# What are some applications of fixed point theorems?

Tags: fixed-point-theorems, banach-fixed-point

What are some nice applications of fixed point theorems? Fixed points of nonexpansive maps? Why are they useful? What are some problems that are still open today in this field? Why did we start working with such maps, spaces?

I was working with nonexpansive maps on space with normal structure, orthogonal convex space.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_theorem and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem#Applications.

Comment: There's such a variety of good answers (existence-uniqueness for ODEs; the Brouwer fixed-point theorem; limits of periodic continued fractions; ...) that I've voted to close as "too broad". (Please see Math.SE's [don't-ask](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page. Particularly, entire books _have been written_ about fixed-point theorems.) Can you perhaps focus your question along the lines of [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)? Thank you.